# Installing Chrome Extension via ExtensionInstallForcelist without Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, active-directory

I try to auto-install a chrome extension on a WIN10 device that have no connection to the internet and thus can not access the Chrome Web Store. So uploading the extension to the CWS is no option. The extension exists as a crx file on a server in a network and on the device.

On Chrome Versions 59 and lower I could install the extension via settings in the registry. When Chrome was started, the user was ask if he wants to install the extension.

For this I used the registry key ExtensionInstallWhitelist and defined the path and version of the extension under the key "[...]/Google/Chrome/Extensions/[ExtensionID]".

But since Version 60 the extension does not appear in Chrome anymore. So I tried to auto-install the extension via an Active Directory domain policy.

I have imported the chrome policy templates and configured the entry ExtensionInstallForcelist (http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist) in the group policy editor. This policy setting is listed on the chrome://policy page in Chrome. But the extension does not appear in Chrome. The ExtensionInstallForcelist entry contains "[ExtensionID];[url where the crx file resides]". I also tested this with an url to an "Update Manifest XML document" which points to the crx file. Neither of them worked.

Does anyone know, if Chrome 60+ still supports this?
Is my configuration incorrect?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you try this with a fresh profile? You could've accidentally blacklisted the extension locally.

Comment: A fresh profile did not solve the issue. Also checked registry and GPO: There is no extension blacklisted.