# Group policy ExtensionInstallForcelist. Extension is not being installed when hosting from local server

Tags: google-chrome-extension, installation, group-policy

[There was a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459392/installing-chrome-extension-via-extensioninstallforcelist-without-chrome-web-sto)

ExtensionInstallForcelist 
1 = pgdgchoanjdbkbbigcnlkfoflffhiheh;http://chrome.local.store:84/updates

Windows 10, member of Domain. 
When I specify https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx, works fine. Switching to my host doesn't work.

My server http://chrome.local.store:84/updates returns XML document:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
  <app appid='pgdgchoanjdbkbbigcnlkfoflffhiheh'>
    <updatecheck codebase='http://chrome.local.store:84/extensionContent' version='0.1' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

And http://chrome.local.store:84/extensionContent returns file with MIME: application/x-chrome-extension and file name = Extension.crx.

Thank you in advance for any clue.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: "Doesn't work" is: Chrome downloads extension code but doesn't install it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue solved with help from chromium forum guys. Many thanks to them.

The solution is to maintain proper extension ID noted from local Chrome extension panel, not from Chrome Store as I mistakenly did.